# kafka topic description with bootstrap servers shows different topic configs

Tags: apache-kafka

```
[root@AdtechQAxxxx ~]# /opt/kafka-2.3.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper 192.169.xx.xx:2181 --describe --topic dl_query
Topic:dl_query  PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 3    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 3,2
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3   Isr: 1,3
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 6    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 9    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 3,2
```

```
[root@AdtechQAxxxx ~]# /opt/kafka-2.3.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --bootstrap-server 192.169.xx.xx:9092 --describe --topic dl_query
Topic:dl_query  PartitionCount:10       ReplicationFactor:2     **Configs:compression.type=gzip,segment.bytes=1073741824,max.message.bytes=100001200**
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 3    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 3,2
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,3   Isr: 1,3
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 6    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
        Topic: dl_query Partition: 9    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 3,2
```

Comment: What is a question?

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka-topics command was updated recently to use the AdminClo class, which requires the bootstrap server instead of Zookeeper, with the eventual goal to remove the dependencies on Zookeeper completely (KIP-500).

As far as why you'd see different topic configs, that data actually is stored in Zookeeper for now, so I'm not sure why you'd see this difference. It's possible the AdminClient returns back the actual broker default configs as well as the topic configs. Otherwise, maybe create a JIRA or try upgrading Kafka?